# Proxy() block scope - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble with the [Proxy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object in Javascript.

This code is working as expected when I pass in a target and no handler:

```js
const scope = new Proxy({a: 2, b: 2}, {});
with (scope) {
    a + b;
}
```

However, when I pass in a handler and no target, it does not work:

```js
const scope = new Proxy({}, {get: function(){ return 2; }});
with (scope) {
    a + b;
}
```

`scope.a == 2 && scope.b == 2` evaluates to `true` in both cases.

Comment: simply because a and b are not defined on the `scope` object in the second one.

Comment: @TKoL but I am using a Proxy that always returns `2`. `scope.a == 2 && scope.b == 2` evaluates to `true` in both cases

Comment: yeah, but the `with` statement doesn't know that. The `with` statement only knows to put into scope the things that are defined in the `scope` object. What do you expect? `With` to put every single possible string into context with a value of 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), here is how JavaScript resolves variables inside `with`:

> JavaScript looks up an unqualified name by searching a scope chain
> associated with the execution context of the script or function
> containing that unqualified name. The 'with' statement adds the given
> object to the head of this scope chain during the evaluation of its
> statement body. If an unqualified name used in the body matches a
> property in the scope chain, then the name is bound to the property
> and the object containing the property. Otherwise a ReferenceError is
> thrown.

That simply means `with` will work for static properties of `scope` but won't work for dynamic getters like the one you created.

This is a simple test which will help determine whether a property will be available in `with` or not:

```js
const working = new Proxy({a: 2, b: 2}, {});
console.log('a' in working);

const notWorking = new Proxy({}, {get: function(){ return 2; }});
console.log('a' in notWorking);
```

Also, `with` is deprecated, here is the modern way to extract properties from an object (it's called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it works for dynamic getters as well):

```js
const scope = new Proxy({}, {get: function(){ return 2; }});
const {a, b} = scope;
console.log(a + b);
```